# How to iterate line by line over element of the list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have the following code to search over the text file and extract the text parts between certain elements: start="a owl:Class"  end=' .\n' and append these text parts as elements of the list.

```
contents = []
with open(r'C:/Users/Jupyter Notebooks/small.ttl', 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
   recording = False
   content = ''
   for line in f:
      if start in line:
         recording = True
      if recording and end in line:
         recording = False
         contents.append(content)
      if recording:
         content += line
      else:
         content = ''
for i in contents
    print (i)
```

The list contents contains two elements which are consisting of strings of text. Every line of text starts with a new line
**First element:**

> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/1075251000119104 a
> owl:Class ;   skos:prefLabel """Acquired left metatarsus adductus"""@en
> ;     skos:notation """1075251000119104"""^^xsd:string ;  skos:altLabel
> """Acquired left metatarsus adductus (disorder)"""@en ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/has_finding_site
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/726438004 ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/has_associated_morphology
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/767172008 ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/occurs_in
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/767023003 ;
> rdfs:subClassOf
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/99701000119102 ;
> rdfs:subClassOf
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/774124003 ;

**Second element:**

> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/10308009 a owl:Class ;
> skos:prefLabel """Argon-42"""@en ;  skos:notation
> """10308009"""^^xsd:string ;  skos:altLabel """42-Ar"""@en ,
> """Argon-42 (substance)"""@en ;   rdfs:subClassOf
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/35016001 ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER
> """900000000000508004~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string
> ;     http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/TYPE_ID
> """900000000000013009"""^^xsd:string ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/CASE_SIGNIFICANCE_ID
> """900000000000017005"""^^xsd:string ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER
> """900000000000509007~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string
> ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/INACTIVATION_INDICATOR
> """723277005"""^^xsd:string ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER
> """900000000000490003~VALUEID~723277005"""^^xsd:string ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER
> """900000000000509007~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string
> ;     http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/TYPE_ID
> """900000000000013009"""^^xsd:string ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/CASE_SIGNIFICANCE_ID
> """900000000000448009"""^^xsd:string ;
> http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER
> """900000000000508004~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string
> ;

I want to go through every list element line by line and check whether the line contains certain string.
For example:

```
if "a:owl Class" in line:
                  print line
```

My problem is that I'm not able to iterate over lines of the elements of the list.

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: Without the actual input file, this is hard to reproduce. Develop your code in stages. The first stage should be opening the file and then reading through the lines and printing them out one at a time. This will let you see if you're reading in the file the way you think you are. You may not be reading in one complete element when you read in a line. How you read it in affects how you process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did this.

First I converted your 2 elements into strings and put them into a list.

```
string1 = 'http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/1075251000119104 a owl:Class ; skos:prefLabel """Acquired left metatarsus adductus"""@en ; skos:notation """1075251000119104"""^^xsd:string ; skos:altLabel """Acquired left metatarsus adductus (disorder)"""@en ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/has_finding_site http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/726438004 ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/has_associated_morphology http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/767172008 ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/occurs_in http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/767023003 ; rdfs:subClassOf http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/99701000119102 ; rdfs:subClassOf http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/774124003 ;'
string2 = 'http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/10308009 a owl:Class ; skos:prefLabel """Argon-42"""@en ; skos:notation """10308009"""^^xsd:string ; skos:altLabel """42-Ar"""@en , """Argon-42 (substance)"""@en ; rdfs:subClassOf http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/35016001 ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER """900000000000508004~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/TYPE_ID """900000000000013009"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/CASE_SIGNIFICANCE_ID """900000000000017005"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER """900000000000509007~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/INACTIVATION_INDICATOR """723277005"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER """900000000000490003~VALUEID~723277005"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER """900000000000509007~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/TYPE_ID """900000000000013009"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/CASE_SIGNIFICANCE_ID """900000000000448009"""^^xsd:string ; http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/SUBSET_MEMBER """900000000000508004~ACCEPTABILITYID~900000000000548007"""^^xsd:string ;'
contents = [string1,string2]
```

You should be able to reproduce my code from this part onwards.

First I iterate over each item in the list.

Then I split each line into a list using the `;` as the separator.

Then I iterate each list over each item in the list looking for your string.

```
for content in contents:
    for line in content.split(';'):
        if 'a owl:Class' in line:
            print(i)
```

Here is my output,

```
http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/1075251000119104 a owl:Class 
http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/10308009 a owl:Class
```

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot, was pretty simple. I also want to search for other lines which occur multiple times inside the certain element such as  rdfs:subClassOf http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/99701000119102 ; rdfs:subClassOf http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/774124003 ;      for content in contents:
    for line in content.split(';'):
        if 'rdfs:subClassOf' in line:
            print(line)      I want somehow to assign two of this rdfs:sublassOf elements only to the first element of the list 1075251000119104 a owl:Class  where they are actuallfrom

Comment: if i answered your question please mark it correct. you should post a new question as the requirements are different. @Oleg_08 it is also hard to see what you want from a comment

Comment: @Oleg_08 if you want to look for duplicates that is pretty easy as well but this question isnt related to that, post a new question and link it in the comment ill try to answer it